How do I ensure the html/body/root height grows to contain dynamically generated content?
I have some content that is dynamically generated from a database (think a web-shop of products) and I cant seem to get the root height to contain it all. Essentially the root grows up until the bottom of the visible screen from load. As-in, it stops when I open the inspector, when I scroll beneath that I can see where it ends.

However, the actual loaded content extends much further, around 4720px... As far as I know, I am guessing this is because the content is loaded after the root is loaded? Not quite sure. Anyways, here is what I have set for my root/body/html styling:
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  width: 100%;

  
}

html{
  width: 100vw;
  
}

html, body, #root{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

Here is the styling for the templated product containers (before the generated content):
fsWrap
    // display: flex
    width: 100%


.fsCont
    display: flex
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    flex-direction: column

.mnPL
    display: flex
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    
    
.mnSub
    width: 100%
    display: flex
    height: 100%
    flex-direction: row

.sbWrap
    background-color: $theme-color-white
    display: flex
    width: 12rem
    border-right: 1px
    border-right-color: rgb(212, 212, 212)
    border-style: solid
    @media (max-width: 600px)
        display: none

.sbCont
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    padding: 2rem 1rem
    width: 100%


You have height: 100vh.
I think maybe what you might want is min-height: 100vh.
The height of an element, unconstrained, will always "grow" to surroud the height of it's contents. You've constrained it by specifying height: 100vh.
Often, in the cases of sticky footers and things like that devs want their body to be at least as tall as the entire screen. So maybe you wanted min-height: 100vh.
